# python docker client only listing running containers

Tags: python, docker

I am facing a strange issue. I have 3 docker container like this -

```
root@dimension-VirtualBox:/home/dimension/neo4j# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                      NAMES
eee581b2f493        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 months ago        Up 22 minutes               0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   skill-ontology
bb99a4eb65ad        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 months ago        Exited (0) 22 minutes ago                                                              skill-ontology-old
2a3a1e300782        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 months ago        Exited (0) 30 hours ago                                                                romantic_mccarthy
```

I wrote a simple python script to list my docker containers using python library for docker. I am using `docker==3.7.0` version of the library. Here is my code. I am using `ubuntu 18.04` machine

```
import docker
# same result with below line
#cli = docker.client.DockerClient(base_url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2375')
cli = docker.DockerClient(base_url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2375')
containers = cli.containers.list()

cont =containers[0]
print(len(containers))
print(cont.short_id)
```

and the result is

```
1
eee581b2f4
```

It prints 1 as the output, but it supposed to print 3.

I have set my ExecStart param to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock` in my `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service file`

Do I need to connect to docker in some different manner in order to get info of all my docker containers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
containers = cli.containers.list(all=True)
```

From the docs:

```
list(**kwargs)

List containers. Similar to the docker ps command.
Parameters: 

    all (bool) – Show all containers. Only running containers are shown by default
```

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.list

Answer (score 1):

Nice thing is:

```
stopped_docker_container = cli.containers.list(all=True, filters={'name':'stopped_container_name'})
```

shows stopped container as

```
stopped_docker_container = cli.containers.list(filters={'name':'stopped_container_name'})
```

wouldn't show stopped container.

That's not so clear in the documentation, but key point is

> cli.containers.list(all=True)

Thanks to @Dmytro Prylipko